# Issue with device after formatting

Tags: permissions, ext4, disk, ext3

I need some help with an SSD disk drive that I am using, or trying to.

I encrypted the SSD with cryptsetup, then I forgot about it (there were some files). I rewrote the disk drive completely (using `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX`, with `sdX` the disk drive in question). I formatted it (`mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdX`). The process worked fine.

Then, I tried to copy files to my drive, by drag and drop (Dolphin). It would not work. It would only work through terminal with `sudo`.

Restarted the computer. I tried to mount the device and copy some files. It apparently worked (drag and drop). But the files were not copied to the device, only to the mount point (which apparently did not sync to the device). However, there is a `lost+found` file, which would not open using dolphin.

I tried to run sync in the terminal. After 30 min, it was still running and unresponsive. Shutdown the computer.

I then used another Linux. It told me that the drive was unreadable (through terminal).

I then reformatted the device: `mkfs.ext3 /dev/sdX`.

After doing this, I still see the `lost+found file`. I cannot access it through Dolphin, cannot delete it through Dolphin. I can only access it through the terminal with `su`. It is empty.

How come the `lost+found` file is still on the device although I reformatted it? What can I do? Should I just leave it?

I still cannot write anything to the device without being `su`. What can I do? where is the issue? Is this an issue with permissions? Or something else?

I use Debian.

Edit1: `fsck` says the device is clean.

Edit2: I tried to use `mkdir` to create a directory in `/media/user/DRIVEPATH/direc`. The result was: Permission denied. Why? I should not need `sudo` for this.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**
The **lost+found** directory you now have is not the same as the one you saw before. It is correct and you should just leave it.

### What creates this directory?

The **lost+found** directory is created automatically for most filesystems by the particular `mkfs` program, and has rwx------ permissions. It is used by various incantations of `fsck`.

### Why is it needed?

When `fsck` is checking a filesystem it might discover inodes which have a reference count that is too low compared to the number of entries it finds for it by scanning the directories. In this case it creates a new entry in the lost+found directory at the root of the filesystem. The permission on lost+found is restrictive as there might be private data in the recovered files which was only restricted in the first place by permissions on higher directories. The directory is created with a reasonable number of empty entries so the fsck programs don't need to allocate space for entries for the recovered files, a relatively complicated operation to do when the data structures are not in a consistent state.

Comment: Why is it not possible to write on the disk? I cannot create any folder or do anything using dolphin.

Comment: What are the permissions on the mount point?

Comment: And what are the permissions on the root of the filesystem? Typically the mkfs programs will not make it rwxrwxrwx.

Comment: Owner is root. I am checking for permissions.

Comment: I noticed something more: For all drives that I manually erased (dd if=... of=...), the owner is changed from user to root, on multiple Linux distributions. How come? Are permissions written into the drive or into the system? This did NOT happen when simply partitioning and formatting a disk without making a full erase with dd.

Comment: Of course permissions are written to the disk, how else would they be persisted? Perhaps you want `sudo chown $USER /media/user/DRIVEPATH`?